# Analysis of sparse time series events with Spark or SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, data-science, data-analysis

I have a set of status change events for users, for simplicty let's say ACTIVATED (A) and DEACTIVATED (D).

Scenario is similar to e.g. a youtube premium subscription, where user might activate or deactivate their subscription multiple times. Hence, both events can occur multiple times for the same user with multiple time points (e.g. days, months) in-between.

**I want to calculate from the event history the number of user with an ACTIVATED status per Month.**

A example timeline could be

```
t: Time point (end of month) of aggregation
u: One user
A: ACTIVATED event
D: DEACTIVATED even

       t:   Jan Feb Mar Apr May
       u1   A               
       u2   A   D           A
       u3       A       D   A
Expected:   2   2   2   1   3
```

The data itself is available in a CSV / table with columns *user-id, event-type time-stamp*. For the example above the raw data would be:

```
user-id event-type time-stamp
u1      A          2020-Jan-01
u2      A          2020-Jan-15
u2      D          2020-Feb-05
u2      A          2020-May-17
u3      A          2020-Feb-04
u3      D          2020-Apr-10
u3      A          2020-May-09
```

Note, that even-though I want to have the count at the end of each Month, the events of course do not happen all at the same time. One user could also have more than one event in the same month.

The absolute count is not problematic, "*count all users where last event is A*".

The tricky thing is to calculate it for the individual months, where I have no change event. E.g. the Mar in the example timeline.

I can not group-by month, since in Mar no event happened, but I need to be aware, that an ACTIVATION or DEACTIVATION happened the time points before.

I can come up with two approaches:

- Calculate for each time point with an increasing partitioning window in some loop. Hence "*for tCursor in Jan to May do: count all users where last event in rang 'Jan - tCursor' is ACTIVATED*".
- Populate the history with redundant events in the time granularity of interest with some pre-processing loop for each user. Then I can avoid the iteratively increased time window.

Both approaches seem somewhat rough (though they would work).

Is there some good alternative? Maybe some magic Spark function that I should be aware off?

Happy to get some input here. I am not 100% sure what to google for, too. I would think there might be even a name for this general issue, since like said, all on / off subscription services with sparse events should have the same issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify what is the output that you are expecting based on the sample data that you have posted in the question?

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data or be clear that the times are in columns.

Comment: I tried to make it more clear now by talking only about months and adding more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot the data, aggregate, and use window functions:

```
with t as (
      select userid, 't1' as t,
             (case when t1 = 'A' then 1 else -1 end)
      from t
      where t1 in ('A', 'D')
      union all
      select userid, 't2' as t,
             (case when t2 = 'A' then 1 else -1 end)
      from t
      where t2 in ('A', 'D')
      union all
      . . .   -- need to repeat for all times
     )
select t, sum(inc) as change_at_time,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by t) as active_on_day
from t
group by t
order by t;
```

The `'t1'` is whatever the time is that is represented by the column.  It might really be a number (your question is not clear on the representation of the data).

The query would be simpler if you simply had rows with `userid`, `time`, and `'A'`/`'D'` rather then having the values splayed across many columns.

Comment: I updated the question. The time table is just to illustrate the scenario. The raw data is available as tuples userid, time, event type.

Comment: I get the idea with the usage of addition / subtraction. Makes sense. 

In my updated description I highlighted, that my events do not happen all at the same time, and there is potentially more than one event per time frame. 

But I realise, that this means simply I need to normalise my event time to monthly granularity and then do the window sum. For the total sum, the order of the events do no matter anymore if I translate them to +1 / -1.